# How do I get distinctive error logs in vite

Tags: vite, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to debug build errors that should show when I run `pnpm run build` instead of `vite build`.

However, it seems that the logs generated during the build process is too ambiguous.

I can't pinpoint errors from this log. Any ideas on how to debug this in a better way or make the log more distinctive?

The error that shows everytime:

```
error during build:
ParseError: Unexpected token

r/parse/read/script.js:50:10)
    at tag (file:///C:/Users/nazmu/Documents/TechHarbor/FPV2/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/state/tag.js:203:27)
    at new Parser (file:///C:/Users/nazmu/Documents/TechHarbor/FPV2/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/index.js:9r/parse/read/script.js:50:10)
    at tag (file:///C:/Users/nazmu/Documents/TechHarbor/FPV2/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/state/tag.js:203:27)
    at new Parser (file:///C:/Users/nazmu/Documents/TechHarbor/FPV2/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/index.js:91:12)
    at parse (file:///C:/Users/nazmu/Documents/TechHarbor/FPV2/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/index.js:268:17)
    at Module.compile (file:///C:/Users/nazmu/Documents/TechHarbor/FPV2/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/index.js:136:14)
    at compileSvelte (file:///C:/Users/nazmu/Documents/TechHarbor/FPV2/node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+vite-plugin-svelte@3.0.2_svelte@4.2.12_vite@5.1.6/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/src/utils/compile.js:147:22)
    at async Object.transform (file:///C:/Users/nazmu/Documents/TechHarbor/FPV2/node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+vite-plugin-svelte@3.0.2_svelte@4.2.12_vite@5.1.6/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/src/index.js:152:20)`
```